# My mysql database gets disconnected from my java application

Tags: java, mysql

My problem is as follows, I have a Java desktop application with the mysql database, the application runs normal and a few minutes later it loses the connection to the database, all the methods I have that pull information from the database are not caught doing the system brake. When I enter phpmyadmin it asks for username and password and when I put it does not accept, it always goes wrong as if it had erred the data, after a few minutes the connection is reestablished, but then the problem comes back. If I restart the bank or the system the problem goes away, but back. Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this problem? Thanks in advance and Sorry for my awful English.

the mistakes:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwhuJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBuG6.png)

Comment: Your english is fine, no need to apologize for that. What you question fails to display is exact error messages. Can you include those? What does "not caught doing the system break" mean? What is "restart the bank"?

Comment: There's not enough information to diagnose the issue. But the problem description does sound like behavior we would observe on a Windows system under heavy load, churning database connections causing TCP port exhaustion. But most java web apps make use of database connection pools that are appropriately sized, and avoid churning database connections.

Comment: The error that returning me in Netbeans is a null pointer exception error inside my search method in the database, as if it had nothing inside the tables. What I meant is that the system hangs and only comes back to normal if I go out and enter the xampp or close and open my application.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to the forum, how do I get my system command lines to better diagnose?